# Can I attach a deck to floating slab building?

Tags: deck, slab

I have a garage that was built on a "floating slab".  I want to attach a deck to this garage using a ledger board at the garage, and then posts with a beam at the other end.  If I put the posts in below the frost line, they will be stable and stay put.  But the garage supposedly moves over time (floating slab), right?  Is there a way to do this safely?

Comment: How far from the deck to the ground?

Comment: Using a ledger board usually requires a permit. (They want to make sure the ledger is installed properly.)  Check local rules

Comment: You'll have to clarify what "floating slab" means to you. Does it have a thickened edge footing? Is it insulated? What's your frost depth?